# How to prove the sheafification is a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I know that this question might be too easy for you, but I have to study on my own, so please explain for me.

In the page 64, Hartshone defined the sheafification of a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ by assign for each open set $U$ a set $\mathcal{F}^{+}(U)$ containing all the function $s$ from $U$ to $\cup_{P\in U}\mathcal{F}_{P}$, satisfying some specific conditions.

I can see that $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ is a presheaf.

My question is: How can I prove that $\mathcal{F}^{+}$ is a sheaf by proving it satisfies two gluing condition (on page 61). I really want to see that proof rigorously.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your problems? For example, what exactly is your problem with verifying sheaf axiom no.1 (=3. in Hartshorne's definition)?

Comment: Hint: the sheaf associated to the presheaf is basically *defined* so that local objects that intersect well can be glued. Try to get a clear picture of what the associated sheaf actually is, locally.

Answer (score 15):

As stated in the comments, the axioms of sheaf can be checked directly using the conditions imposed on the functions in $\mathcal{F}^+ (U)$. Let's just write them down as they are presented in Hartshorne's book:

1. for each $P\in U$, we have $s(P)\in \mathcal{F}_P$;
2. for each $P\in U$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $P$, contained in $U$, and an element $t\in \mathcal{F}(V)$ such that for all $Q\in V$ the germ $t_Q$ of $t$ at $Q$ is equal to $s(Q)$.

Using these we need to prove two conditions for $\mathcal{F}^+$ being a sheaf.

First: let $U$ be an open set, $ \lbrace V_i \rbrace $ an open covering of $U$, and $s\in \mathcal{F}^+(U) $ such that $s_{|V_i}=0$ for all $i$. Then $s$ must be equal to $0$.

This is true: $s=0$ means that $s(P)=0$ for each $P$ in $U$. Take any $P$ in $U$, then there exists an open set $V_i$ that contains $P$, hence $0=s_{|V_i}(P)=s(P)$, and this verifies the axiom.

Second: suppose we have, for each $i$, an element $s_i\in \mathcal{F}^+(V_i)$, so that $s_{i|V_i \cap V_j}=s_{j|V_i\cap V_j}$ whenever this makes sense. Then we have to find $s\in \mathcal{F}^+(U)$ such that $s_i=s_{|V_i}$ for each $i$.

Such $s$ can be constructed directly: take any point $P$ in $U$ and the open set $V_i$ which contains $P$, and define $s(P)=s_i(P)$. This is a good definition because the $s_i$'s agree on the intersections, all is left to check is that $s$ satisfies the conditions of the sheafification. The first one is ok, because it's verified by the $s_i$'s, for the second one, just consider that you can apply the condition to the $s_i$: this will give you an open neighborhood $W_i$ contained in $V_i$ and containing $P$, with an element $t_i\in \mathcal{F}(W_i)$ as above. Since $W_i$ is open in $V_i$, which is open in $U$, the set $W_i$ is suitable also for the function $s$ we have just defined.

This proves that $\mathcal{F}^+$ is a sheaf, and a bit more of similar manipulation yields that all of its stalks are isomorphic to the stalks of $\mathcal{F}$.

I hope this can work.

P.S. There is a very compact way to describe the sheafification (easy to remember at least): one can write
$$
\mathcal{F}^+(U)=\varprojlim_{p\in U}\varinjlim_{p\in V} \mathcal{F}(V)
$$

Comment: @Franko Can you explain the last remark you mentioned?

Comment: Taking the direct limit of $\mathcal F(V)$ is the same as taking the stalk of $\mathcal F$ at $p$. Then, the sheafification can be though of as a process of gluing the stalks with an inverse limit. To see this, one needs to chase through the definitions of limits and of sheafification, and stalk.

Comment: I think the key point where some beginners got stuck in is the definition of $s$ ($s(P)=s_i(P)$). @Franco Do you remember which books where you read this proof? Thanks.

Comment: The same proof appears in Cutkosky's _Introduction to Algebraic_. (Proposition 11.12 on page 187.)
However, there is a typo. On page 188, line 7, $x(p)=(x_i)_p$ should be $x(p)=x_i(p)$. 
It is the same as $s(P)=s_i(P)$ at here.

Comment: @bfhaha thanks for the reference, I think at the time I did it as an exercise ( Hartshorne's \emph{Algebraic geometry} Chp. II, Proposition-Definition 1.2 leaves this verification to the reader)

Comment: @Franco Yeah. I know! He said "one can verify immdediately!" ^^" and Wedhorn's Algebraic geometry also said that "it is easy to check" (Proposition 2.24).